# Unable to find image 'nvidia/cuda:11.0-base' locally when testing nvidia-docker2 setup

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, docker

I am following the [official NVIDIA instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/1.8.1/install-guide.html) for installing nvidia-docker2. I get this error.

```
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ curl https://get.docker.com | sh \
  && sudo systemctl --now enable docker
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 21927  100 21927    0     0   186k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  187k
# Executing docker install script, commit: e5543d473431b782227f8908005543bb4389b8de
Warning: the "docker" command appears to already exist on this system.

If you already have Docker installed, this script can cause trouble, which is
why we're displaying this warning and provide the opportunity to cancel the
installation.

If you installed the current Docker package using this script and are using it
again to update Docker, you can safely ignore this message.

You may press Ctrl+C now to abort this script.
+ sleep 20
^C
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) \
   && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add - \
   && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
#deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
#deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/$distribution/nvidia-container-runtime.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-runtime.list
deb https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
deb https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/ubuntu18.04/$(ARCH) /
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-8.9.5.29  InRelease [1,572 B]
Ign:2 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ InRelease
Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-8.9.5.29  InRelease [1,572 B]                               
Ign:3 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Release                                                                                           
Ign:4 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Packages                                                                                   
Ign:5 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign:6 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en                                                                            
Ign:4 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Packages                                                                                  
Ign:5 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign:6 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en                                                      
Ign:4 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Packages                         
Ign:5 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en_US                
Ign:6 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en                   
Hit:4 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Packages                         
Ign:5 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en_US                
Get:7 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,503 B]
Ign:6 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en                                              
Get:8 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,494 B]
Ign:5 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en_US                             
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:6 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en                   
Ign:5 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en_US                
Get:10 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,484 B]
Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Ign:6 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en                                                                                                                                                          
Ign:5 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en_US                                                                                                                                                       
Ign:6 http://10.82.164.106/debs ./ Translation-en                                                                                                                                                          
Hit:12 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease                                                                                                               
Get:13 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,474 B]                                                                                                                       
Hit:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Hit:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Hit:16 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                             
Hit:17 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:18 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:19 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                      
Hit:20 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                                                                        
Hit:21 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                      
Get:22 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/ubuntu18.04/amd64  Packages [12.4 kB]                                
Get:23 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/ubuntu18.04/amd64  Packages [976 B]                                                               
Hit:24 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                     
Hit:25 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                
Get:26 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  Packages [4,488 B]                
Hit:27 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                 
Hit:28 https://librealsense.intel.com/Debian/apt-repo jammy InRelease        
Fetched 23.8 kB in 6s (4,201 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/ubuntu18.04/amd64/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/ubuntu18.04/amd64/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-docker2 is already the newest version (2.13.0-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-cccl-11-7 cuda-command-line-tools-11-7 cuda-compiler-11-7 cuda-cudart-11-7 cuda-cudart-dev-11-7 cuda-cuobjdump-11-7 cuda-cupti-11-7 cuda-cupti-dev-11-7 cuda-cuxxfilt-11-7 cuda-demo-suite-11-7
  cuda-documentation-11-7 cuda-driver-dev-11-7 cuda-gdb-11-7 cuda-libraries-11-7 cuda-libraries-dev-11-7 cuda-memcheck-11-7 cuda-nsight-11-7 cuda-nsight-compute-11-7 cuda-nsight-systems-11-7
  cuda-nvcc-11-7 cuda-nvdisasm-11-7 cuda-nvml-dev-11-7 cuda-nvprof-11-7 cuda-nvprune-11-7 cuda-nvrtc-11-7 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-7 cuda-nvtx-11-7 cuda-nvvp-11-7 cuda-runtime-11-7 cuda-sanitizer-11-7
  cuda-toolkit-11-7 cuda-toolkit-11-7-config-common cuda-tools-11-7 cuda-visual-tools-11-7 gds-tools-11-7 libcublas-11-7 libcublas-dev-11-7 libcufft-11-7 libcufft-dev-11-7 libcufile-11-7
  libcufile-dev-11-7 libcurand-11-7 libcurand-dev-11-7 libcusolver-11-7 libcusolver-dev-11-7 libcusparse-11-7 libcusparse-dev-11-7 libnpp-11-7 libnpp-dev-11-7 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvjpeg-11-7
  libnvjpeg-dev-11-7 nsight-compute-2022.2.1 nsight-systems-2022.1.3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ sudo systemctl restart docker
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.0-base nvidia-smi
Unable to find image 'nvidia/cuda:11.0-base' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for nvidia/cuda:11.0-base not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

sys info:

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ nvidia-docker --version
Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
(base) mona@ada:~$ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
(base) mona@ada:~$ uname -a
Linux ada 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) mona@ada:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

In case needed, I need `nvidia-docker2` for running the commands in this tutorial. https://github.com/zju3dv/pvnet/blob/master/docker/how-to-docker.md

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ sudo apt show nvidia-docker2
Package: nvidia-docker2
Version: 2.13.0-1
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Maintainer: NVIDIA CORPORATION <cudatools@nvidia.com>
Installed-Size: 27.6 kB
Depends: nvidia-container-toolkit (>= 1.13.0-1), docker-ce (>= 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu) | docker-ee (>= 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu) | docker.io (>= 18.06.0) | moby-engine
Breaks: nvidia-docker (<< 2.0.0)
Replaces: nvidia-docker (<< 2.0.0)
Homepage: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki
Download-Size: 6,876 B
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  Packages
Description: nvidia-docker CLI wrapper
 Replaces nvidia-docker with a new implementation based on the NVIDIA Container Toolkit

N: There are 33 additional records. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer credits to Devansh Gupta

First browse to [this link](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags?page=1&name=%25-base) to figure which exact docker to download.

Then follow along:

```
(base) mona@ada:~$  docker pull nvidia/cuda:11.1.1-base-ubi8
11.1.1-base-ubi8: Pulling from nvidia/cuda
94343313ec15: Pull complete 
30cb60717d1b: Pull complete 
578bdc385fde: Pull complete 
c3b8193f59fc: Pull complete 
02bb93d943d6: Pull complete 
9ce778af9a5c: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:1ec6ecabc84142abb181fd9871434368842218055049a9a48929d8ce135adc09
Status: Downloaded newer image for nvidia/cuda:11.1.1-base-ubi8
docker.io/nvidia/cuda:11.1.1-base-ubi8
(base) mona@ada:~$ sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.1.1-base-ubi8  nvidia-smi
[sudo] password for mona: 
Thu Nov 16 16:17:30 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.104.12             Driver Version: 535.104.12   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX 6000 Ada Gene...    On  | 00000000:52:00.0  On |                  Off |
| 30%   44C    P8              32W / 300W |   1172MiB / 49140MiB |     37%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```